# C++ Arabic UTF8 string to CString

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, mfc, c-strings

in a Visual Studio 2008 MFC project I've to manage strings in UTF8 containing arabic cities and searching onlines I write this little piece of code:

```
    CString MyClass::convertString(string input) {
    int l = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t *str = new wchar_t[l];
    int r = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), -1, str, l);
    CString output = str;
    delete str ;
    return output;
}
```

When I try to convert a string it remains the same and if I try to print these two string the result is the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "[I]f I try to print these two string[s] the result is the same."  What result is that exactly, based on what input?  And what exactly do you mean by "print?"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the input string is "الرياض‎" but if I try to show these two strings with a message box I get "1J'6" for both.

Comment: @Stefano: The translation is correct.  The bug is in the printing code.

Comment: Try using `CStringW` instead of `CString` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to display the strings?  I suspect it's simply a matter of the font in the message box not supporting the glyphs for Arabic.

Comment: If we interpret `"1J'6"` as a UTF16 string being interpreted as any code page, then the string is... "ㅊ✶".  Well, that's a dead end.  Actually... you know what "1J'6" looks like to me?  0x314A2736... I bet you're printing the _pointer_!  Would definitely explain why both strings are equal!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to convert strings to UTF-8 for display purposes.  There is no UTF-8 charset than will allow you to display them correctly.  If your already have them in Unicode, just keep them in Unicode.  I would build your application in Unicode and avoid MBCS if you can.  It makes life easier.  Otherwise, for displaying those Arabic strings, you would have to convert them to the Arabic codepage and then use an Arabic font/charset to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replies. I've found a solution; the string in input was not encoded in UTF8 (I should have check it before posting on Stackoverflow), then I edited the code changing the output from CString to wstring.

```
    wstring MyClass::convertString(string input) {
    int l = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t *str = new wchar_t[l];
    int r = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), -1, str, l1);
    wstring output = wstring(str);
    delete str ;
    return output
}
```

Now everything works fine. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you need to use `delete[] str` instead of `delete str`. Also, you should use `input.length()` instead of -1, and then use `wstring(str, r)` instead of `wstring(str)`. You might also consider eliminating `str` altogether and just have `MultiByteToWideChar()` write the converted data directly into `output` instead.